# StAX createXMLEventReader should I use a BufferedReader?

Tags: java, stax

```
xmlInputFactory.createXMLEventReader(new FileInputStream(myFile));
```

Should I use a BufferedReader-decorator for the FIS or is the XMLInputFactory clever enough to decorate the FileInputStream itself?

Comment: i assume you mean a BufferedInputStream decorator?

Comment: Not necessarily, createXMLEventReader also has an overload for Reader. So I Could use BufferedReader(InputStreamReader(FileInputStream)) instead.

Comment: yes, you could do that if you wanted to corrupt the xml for some odd reason.

Comment: I don't get what you mean - no I don't want to corrupt the XML. I just ask for performance reasons: Is the created XMLEventReader able to load the XML file faster if I use a BufferedInputStream or BufferedReader compared to using a FileInputStream directly.

Comment: i was referring to the use of a BufferedReader specifically.  in your comment above, you are converting the xml bytes to chars using the platform character encoding, which is a bad idea.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

seems like you should be able to test this pretty easily.  try with and without a BufferedInputStream and see which one is faster.  in general, adding *extra* BufferedInputStreams does not usually add much overhead as they are designed to handle this situation gracefully.